# How can I add multiple functions with a same name for ZeroBrane's API?

Tags: zerobrane

I found in the API file for ZeroBrane I can only add one name for one function. If I add multiple functions with a same name, then I type the name in the lua IDE, it can only show me a single tip.

Answer (score 0):

> If I add multiple functions with a same name, then I type the name in the lua IDE, it can only show me a single tip.

This is the current limitation of the support for custom APIs in the IDE, but there is a [ticket that requests support for function overloads](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/issues/771), so you may want to follow it for any progress on this feature.